# jekyll Include tag becomes regular text when I go to site page through link from index.html

Tags: github, include, jekyll

I have an index.html that contains a {% include header.html %} tag and renders as it should when I go to its page. When I click a link to another page from that index.html, the {% include header.html %} on the other page shows up on the site as regular text and does not display the html. Please let me know what i can do. I have no idea whats going on.

Comment: Can we see your source? A github repository maybe ?

Comment: yes. ill post in the question.